# Order by other property instead of Key when selecting from index OrientDB

Tags: orientdb-2.1

I am using **Orient DB 2.1.16**. I have a vertex class in orientDB called **person**, I also created a property for person class called **name**. I added a **full text index** on that property called **person.name**.Upon searching on index I can only order by key, is there any other way to search on index **INDEX:person.name** but order by another property of property of person like **age** `SELECT FROM INDEX:person.name WHERE KEY CONTAINSTEXT 'abc' ORDER BY KEY ASC` works fine but `SELECT FROM INDEX:person.name WHERE KEY CONTAINSTEXT 'abc' ORDER BY age ASC` gives error saying when selecting from index can only order by key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of Selecting from an **index** will not contain unindexed properties. If you want to order by a field which is not part of the index, you need to select the related field also.

E.g.:

```
SELECT name, age FROM (SELECT EXPAND(rid) FROM INDEX:person.name WHERE
KEY CONTAINSTEXT 'abc') ORDER BY age ASC
```

More simple solution is to query properties from original vertex with the **ContainsText** operator:

```
SELECT name, age from person WHERE (name CONTAINSTEXT 'abc') ORDER BY age ASC
```